# Error while installing package developed with cliff

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I wrote a command line tool with cliff 2.3.0, tested on my laptop (Mac, Python 2.7.12). When I was tried to install it (`python setup.py install`) on a server (Linux, Python 2.7.2), I encountered this error:

```
Installed /private/tmp/easy_install-EGMO15/cliff-2.3.0/pbr-1.10.0-py2.7.egg

ERROR:root:Error parsing

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/private/tmp/easy_install-EGMO15/cliff-2.3.0/pbr-1.10.0-> py2.7.egg/pbr/core.py", line 111, in pbr
    attrs = util.cfg_to_args(path, dist.script_args)   File "/private/tmp/easy_install-EGMO15/cliff-2.3.0/pbr-1.10.0-py2.7.egg/pbr/util.py", line 248, in cfg_to_args
    kwargs = setup_cfg_to_setup_kwargs(config, script_args)   File "/private/tmp/easy_install-EGMO15/cliff-2.3.0/pbr-1.10.0-py2.7.egg/pbr/util.py", line 431, in setup_cfg_to_setup_kwargs
    if pkg_resources.evaluate_marker('(%s)' % env_marker):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'evaluate_marker' error: Setup script exited with error in setup command: Error parsing /private/tmp/easy_install-EGMO15/cliff-2.3.0/setup.cfg: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'evaluate_marker'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server may have a (much) older version of the `setuptools` package installed (which provides the `pkg_resources` module).  The `evaluate_marker` method looks as if it first showed up at the end of 2014, so if you're using an older system it is possible that method is not available.

Depending on your environment, you may be able to simply `pip install -U setuptools`, or you may need to see if your distribution has a newer isntallable package available.

If you can update your question to include details about your server's operating environment (what distribution and version are you running? What version of Python? What version of `setuptools`?), we can probably provide a more complete answer.

**Update**

For example, Ubuntu 12.04 only has setuptools 0.6, and the `pkg_resources` module (which is packaged in the `python-pkg-resources` package) does not have the `evaluate_marker` method:

```
# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.evaluate_marker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'evaluate_marker'
```

In this environment, I can install `pip`:

```
# apt-get install python-pip
```

And then upgrade the installed version of `setuptools`:

```
# pip install -U setuptools
```

And now:

```
# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.evaluate_marker
<function evaluate_marker at 0x1535050>
>>>
```

**NB** Upgrading distribution packages (e.g., things installed by `apt-get` in this example) using `pip` can often lead to sadness and heartache, and you are much better off if you are able to upgrade the underlying environment to one where such workarounds are not necessary.  Alternatively, running your code from a Python virtual environment (so that your upgraded packages do not override system packages) is also a technically better solution.